# First difference stationary process

Tags: stationarity

I have a question regarding an I(1) process.

Suppose we have the following equation:

$$
Y_0 = \alpha_1Y_{-1}+\alpha_2Y_{-2}+\alpha_3Y_{-3}+...+\alpha_4Y_{-4} 
$$
$$
with \sum\limits_{i=1}^4 \alpha_{i} = 1
$$

How can I prove mathematically that Y is already an I(1) process, given that the sum of the lagged coefficients are equal to one?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: One equation does not prove anything about the properties of the _process_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Dilip says, your notation is wrong, it should be general as follows, having $t$ in it, together with its ch. eqn:
$$Y_t=\sum_{i=1}^4\alpha_iY_{t-i}\rightarrow 1=\sum_{i=1}^4\alpha_iL^i$$

If the ch. eqn. has $(1-L)^d$ as a factor, than it is $I(d)$. Checking if at least we have $(1-L)$ in its factorization is easy, because if it is, $L=1$ should be a root of the characteristic equation. Substituting into the above equation yieds:
$$1=\sum_{i=1}^4\alpha_i$$
which is already true. So, $L=1$ is a root of the characteristic equation, and $Y_t$ is at least $I(1)$. We can't say anything about larger orders.